# Not able to retrieve the Date and Time fields data from redis DB by using RediSearch

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redisclient

We are using RediSearch (io.rediseach.client.Cleint) in spring boot application for getting the records from redis DB. We are not able to get the date and time column values(ex: date as 07/21/2021 and time as 09:12) and other columns are retrieved properly. Could you please help me on this and is there anything we need to add in search query)

below is the code for reference

`private final Client client; Query q = new Query("@columnName:"+columnValue);  ex: Query q = new Query("@empName:"+raju); SearchResult result = client.search(q);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing escaping on the query side.

RediSearch parser requires users to escape special characters.

You can read more about it at [Controlling Text Tokenization and Escaping](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Escaping/) on redisearch.io.